# finding a point and its angle on a cubic Bezier curve in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, curve, bezier, cubic-bezier

I need to find a point and its angle on a cubic Bezier curve that can be dynamically changed using JavaScript.
I asked ChatGPT about this, to which it generated the following code, but the angle is not calculated correctly, where am I or is ChatGPT wrong?

```
      // Initialize with some initial control points
      let points = [
        { x: 50, y: 100 }, // Start point
        { x: 150, y: 50 }, // First control point
        { x: 250, y: 150 }, // Second control point
        { x: 350, y: 100 } // End point
      ];

      function deCasteljau(points, t) {
        if (points.length === 1) {
          return points[0];
        }

        const newPoints = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < points.length - 1; i++) {
          const x = (1 - t) * points[i].x + t * points[i + 1].x;
          const y = (1 - t) * points[i].y + t * points[i + 1].y;
          newPoints.push({ x, y });
        }

        return deCasteljau(newPoints, t);
      }

      function cubicBezierDerivative(points, t) {
        const derivativePoints = [];
        const n = points.length - 1;
        for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            const dx = n * (points[i + 1].x - points[i].x);
            const dy = n * (points[i + 1].y - points[i].y);
            derivativePoints.push({ x: dx, y: dy });
        }
        return derivativePoints;
      }


      function bezierAngle(points, t) {
        const dPoints = cubicBezierDerivative(points, t);
        const point = deCasteljau(points, t);
        const dx = dPoints[0].x;
        const dy = dPoints[0].y;
        const radian = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
        //const angle = radian*180/Math.PI;
        return radian;
      }
      const point = deCasteljau(points, 0.9);
          
      const angle = bezierAngle(points, 0.9);
```

---

live demo:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('splineCanvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

let points = []; // Array to hold control points
let selectedPointIndex = -1; // Index of the currently selected control point

// Event listener for mouse down to select control point
canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(event) {
    const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    const mouseX = event.clientX - rect.left;
    const mouseY = event.clientY - rect.top;

    // Check if mouse is over any control point
    for (let i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
        const dx = points[i].x - mouseX;
        const dy = points[i].y - mouseY;
        const dist = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
        if (dist < 6) { // 6 is the radius for selecting control point
            selectedPointIndex = i;
            canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
            canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp);
            break;
        }
    }
});

// Event listener for mouse move to update control point position
function onMouseMove(event) {
    const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    const mouseX = event.clientX - rect.left;
    const mouseY = event.clientY - rect.top;

    points[selectedPointIndex].x = mouseX;
    points[selectedPointIndex].y = mouseY;
    drawSpline();
}

// Event listener for mouse up to stop updating control point position
function onMouseUp() {
    canvas.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
    canvas.removeEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp);
    selectedPointIndex = -1;
}

let testAngle = 65;

// Draw spline function
function drawSpline() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(points[0].x, points[0].y);

    for (let i = 1; i < points.length - 2; i+=3) {
        ctx.bezierCurveTo(
          points[i].x, 
          points[i].y,
          points[i+1].x,
          points[i+1].y,
          points[i+2].x,
          points[i+2].y,
        );
    }

    ctx.stroke();

    // Draw control points
    for (const point of points) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(point.x, point.y, 6, 0, Math.PI * 2);
        ctx.fillStyle = "#ff0000";
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.closePath();
    }

    const point = deCasteljau(points, 0.9);
    //console.log('point = ', point);
    const angle = bezierAngle(points, 0.9);
    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(point.x, point.y);
    ctx.rotate(angle);
    ctx.translate(-point.x, -point.y);

    ctx.fillStyle = "green";
    ctx.fillRect(point.x-5, point.y-5, 10, 10);
    ctx.restore();
}

// Initialize with some initial control points
points = [
  { x: 50, y: 100 }, // Start point
  { x: 150, y: 50 }, // First control point
  { x: 250, y: 150 }, // Second control point
  { x: 350, y: 100 } // End point
];

function deCasteljau(points, t) {
  if (points.length === 1) {
    return points[0];
  }

  const newPoints = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < points.length - 1; i++) {
    const x = (1 - t) * points[i].x + t * points[i + 1].x;
    const y = (1 - t) * points[i].y + t * points[i + 1].y;
    newPoints.push({ x, y });
  }

  return deCasteljau(newPoints, t);
}

function cubicBezierDerivative(points, t) {
  const derivativePoints = [];
  const n = points.length - 1;
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      const dx = n * (points[i + 1].x - points[i].x);
      const dy = n * (points[i + 1].y - points[i].y);
      derivativePoints.push({ x: dx, y: dy });
  }
  return derivativePoints;
}


function bezierAngle(points, t) {
  const dPoints = cubicBezierDerivative(points, t);
  const point = deCasteljau(points, t);
  const dx = dPoints[0].x;
  const dy = dPoints[0].y;
  const radian = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
  //const angle = radian*180/Math.PI;
  return radian;
}

drawSpline();
```

```html
<canvas id="splineCanvas" width="600" height="300"></canvas>
```

Comment: you said you need (tangent ... ?) angle, not derivative. the one-before-last step in the point calculation in deCasteljau algorithm has the two points - the start and end point of the tangent segment for the parameter t.

Comment: ChatGPT is not a code writing service, no matter how much people claim it is: it's _just_ an autocomplete, and it knows _nothing_ about what code is, let alone what _working_ code is, or what _good_ code is, so if you asked ChatGPT to write you some code, and it doesn't work: that's unfortunate, but SO [isn't here to help fix ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned). It's here to help _you_ with _your_ programming problem, so: run through the code, where do you see it do the wrong thing, and what have you tried to fix it?

Comment: `for (let i = 1; i < points.length - 2; i+=3) {`  ... Do you mind explaining what is this loop doing in your code?

Comment: `const point = deCasteljau(points, t);` ... what is that doing in the function bezierAngle? .... looks like just an extra variable for no reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just from a math perspective I question what you mean by "finding a point and its angle" points in 2D space, like you represented in the points array, are just `{x, y}` there is no angle ...

---

What we can do is calculate the angle between two points, and looks like that is what the functions `cubicBezierDerivative` & `bezierAngle` attempted to do, I'm assuming that is what you need/ask, I would base my code below on that, also I'm going to assume that the point returned by `function deCasteljau` is correct, I'm not going to spend any research time into how is that doing what is doing.

So we can modify the `function bezierAngle` to return the angle between two given points, the current point and and what I call "next" point:

```
    const point = deCasteljau(points, x);
    const next = deCasteljau(points, x + 0.01);
    const angle = bezierAngle([point, next]);
```

with the angle between those two the square we draw is "facing" the right way.

In the code below you will see a new function `drawRect` that is where we draw the squares, and since it is now a function we can have multiple square with different colors

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('splineCanvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

let points = [
  { x: 50,  y: 100 }, // Start point
  { x: 170, y: 20  }, // First control point
  { x: 240, y: 170 }, // Second control point
  { x: 350, y: 10  }  // End point
]
let selectedPointIndex = -1;

// Event listener for mouse down to select control point
canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(event) {
    const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    const mouseX = event.clientX - rect.left;
    const mouseY = event.clientY - rect.top;

    // Check if mouse is over any control point
    for (let i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
        const dx = points[i].x - mouseX;
        const dy = points[i].y - mouseY;
        const dist = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
        if (dist < 6) { // 6 is the radius for selecting control point
            selectedPointIndex = i;
            canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
            canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp);
            break;
        }
    }
});

// Event listener for mouse move to update control point position
function onMouseMove(event) {
    const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    const mouseX = event.clientX - rect.left;
    const mouseY = event.clientY - rect.top;

    points[selectedPointIndex].x = mouseX;
    points[selectedPointIndex].y = mouseY;
    drawSpline();
}

// Event listener for mouse up to stop updating control point position
function onMouseUp() {
    canvas.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
    canvas.removeEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp);
    selectedPointIndex = -1;
}

let testAngle = 65;

// Draw spline function
function drawSpline() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(points[0].x, points[0].y);

    ctx.bezierCurveTo(
      points[1].x, points[1].y,
      points[2].x, points[2].y,
      points[3].x, points[3].y,
    );
    ctx.stroke();

    // Draw control points
    for (const point of points) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(point.x, point.y, 6, 0, Math.PI * 2);
        ctx.fillStyle = "#ff0000";
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.closePath();
    }
   drawRect(0.2, "cyan")
   drawRect(0.5, "blue")
   drawRect(0.8, "green")
}

function drawRect(x, color) {
    const point = deCasteljau(points, x);
    const next = deCasteljau(points, x + 0.01);
    const angle = bezierAngle([point, next]);
    ctx.save();
    ctx.globalAlpha = 0.6
    ctx.translate(point.x, point.y);
    ctx.rotate(angle);
    ctx.translate(-point.x, -point.y);

    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fillRect(point.x-15, point.y-15, 30, 30);
    //ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    //ctx.fillText(angle, point.x, point.y);
    ctx.restore();
}

function deCasteljau(points, t) {
  if (points.length === 1) {
    return points[0];
  }

  const newPoints = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < points.length - 1; i++) {
    const x = (1 - t) * points[i].x + t * points[i + 1].x;
    const y = (1 - t) * points[i].y + t * points[i + 1].y;
    newPoints.push({ x, y });
  }

  return deCasteljau(newPoints, t);
}

function bezierAngle(points) {
  const dx = points[1].x - points[0].x;
  const dy = points[1].y - points[0].y;
  const radian = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
  return radian;
}

drawSpline();
```

```html
<canvas id="splineCanvas" width="400" height="180"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Precise tangent at unit position on curve

Example code below gives exact tangent of curve at unit position on bezier.

The example normalizes the tangent to be more useful for various rendering tasks.

Solutions includes quadratic and cubic curves.

To convert the tangent to an angle just use `Math.atan2(tangent.y, tangent.x);` though there is no need as a matrix can be constructed directly from the tangent (no need to mess with rotations, translations, etc...) E.G.  `ctx.setTransform(tangent.x, tangent.y, -tangent.y, tangent.x, pos.x, pos.y);` where `pos` is the position on the curve.

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const TAU = Math.PI * 2;
const Vec2 = (x = 0, y = 0) => ({x, y});
const RotateVec90 = v => Vec2(-v.y, v.x);
const QBez = (p1, cp1, p2) => ({p1, cp1, p2});           // Quadratic bez 3 Vec2 p1, p2 start and end, cp1 control point
const CBez = (p1, cp1, cp2, p2) => ({p1, cp1, cp2, p2}); // Cubic bez 4 Vec2 p1, p2 start and end, cp1, cp2 control points

const Beziers = {
    asArray(bez) {
        return bez.cp2 === undefined ?
            [bez.p1, bez.cp1, bez.p2] :
            [bez.p1, bez.cp1, bez.cp2, bez.p2];
    },
    tangentAt(bez, pos, limit = true, tangent = Vec2()) {  
        if (limit) { pos = Math.min(1, Math.max(0, pos)); }
        if (bez.cp2 === undefined) {   /* is quadratic */
            const a = (1 - pos) * 2;
            const b = pos * 2;
            tangent.x = a * (bez.cp1.x - bez.p1.x) + b * (bez.p2.x - bez.cp1.x);
            tangent.y = a * (bez.cp1.y - bez.p1.y) + b * (bez.p2.y - bez.cp1.y);
        } else {                          /* is cubic */
            const a = (1 - pos)
            const b = 6 * a * pos;        
            const c = a * 3 * a;          
            const d = 3 * pos * pos;      
            tangent.x = -bez.p1.x * c + bez.cp1.x * (c - b) + bez.cp2.x * (b - d) + bez.p2.x * d;
            tangent.y = -bez.p1.y * c + bez.cp1.y * (c - b) + bez.cp2.y * (b - d) + bez.p2.y * d;
        }
        const u = 1.0 / (tangent.x * tangent.x + tangent.y * tangent.y) ** 0.5;
        tangent.x *= u;
        tangent.y *= u;
        return tangent;
    },
    pointAt(bez, pos, limit = true, point = Vec2()) { 
        if (limit) {
            if (pos <= 0) {
                point.x = bez.p1.x;
                point.y = bez.p1.y;
                return point;
            }
            if (pos >= 1) {
                point.x = bez.p2.x;
                point.y = bez.p2.y;
                return point;
            }
        }
        const v1 = Vec2(bez.p1.x, bez.p1.y);
        const v2 = Vec2(bez.cp1.x, bez.cp1.y);
        const c = pos;
        v1.x += (v2.x - v1.x) * c;
        v1.y += (v2.y - v1.y) * c; 
        if (bez.cp2 === undefined) {  /* is quadratic */
            v2.x += (bez.p2.x - v2.x) * c;
            v2.y += (bez.p2.y - v2.y) * c;
            point.x = v1.x + (v2.x - v1.x) * c;
            point.y = v1.y + (v2.y - v1.y) * c;
            return point;
        }
        const v3 = Vec2(bez.cp2.x, bez.cp2.y);
        v2.x += (v3.x - v2.x) * c;
        v2.y += (v3.y - v2.y) * c;
        v3.x += (bez.p2.x - v3.x) * c;
        v3.y += (bez.p2.y - v3.y) * c;
        v1.x += (v2.x - v1.x) * c;
        v1.y += (v2.y - v1.y) * c;
        v2.x += (v3.x - v2.x) * c;
        v2.y += (v3.y - v2.y) * c;
        point.x = v1.x + (v2.x - v1.x) * c;
        point.y = v1.y + (v2.y - v1.y) * c;
        return point;
    },    
};
const Render = {
    draw(bez, width = 2, color = "#000") {
        ctx.lineWidth = width;
        ctx.strokeStyle = color;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.lineTo(bez.p1.x, bez.p1.y);
        if (bez.cp2 === undefined) {   /* is quadratic */
            ctx.quadraticCurveTo(bez.cp1.x, bez.cp1.y, bez.p2.x, bez.p2.y);
        } else {            
            ctx.bezierCurveTo(bez.cp1.x, bez.cp1.y, bez.cp2.x, bez.cp2.y, bez.p2.x, bez.p2.y)
        }
        ctx.stroke();    
    },
    drawPoints(radius, color, ...points) {
        ctx.fillStyle = color;
        ctx.beginPath();
        for (const p of points) {
             ctx.moveTo(p.x + radius, p.y);
             ctx.arc(p.x, p.y, radius, 0, TAU);
        }
        ctx.fill();
    },
    drawVector(pos, unitVec, len, width = 2, color = "#000") {
        ctx.lineWidth = width;
        ctx.strokeStyle = color;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.lineTo(pos.x, pos.y);
        ctx.lineTo(pos.x + unitVec.x * len, pos.y + unitVec.y * len);
        ctx.stroke();
    }
};

const curve = CBez(Vec2(50, 100), Vec2(170, 10), Vec2(260, 270), Vec2(350, 10));
Render.draw(curve);
Render.drawPoints(4, "#A00", ...Beziers.asArray(curve));
var pos = 0.0;
while (pos <= 1.01) {
    Render.drawVector(Beziers.pointAt(curve, pos, true), RotateVec90(Beziers.tangentAt(curve, pos, true)), 20, 1, "#0A0");
    pos += 0.02;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```